# How do I change time format for messages?

Tags: debian, skype

I'm talking about the new Skype version 8.11.0.4 for Debian. It's a webapp turned into an application. Note that I'm not talking about the old installed version that indeed was not webapp-based. That one is not supported anymore.

How do I change time format for messages?

I need AMPM/24H flexibility and seconds precision.

Comment: What do you call a webapp that is turned into an app?

Comment: Please tell me why you downvoted me. I can improve the question.

Comment: @Mokubai I wasn't suspecting you (except for a vague "what if"). Had I suspected you, I would have just fixed the "webapp" bit, the obvious reason for the downvote.

Comment: Maybe consider adding a picture of what you're seeing and/or specific information on what package you're using.

Comment: @Seth Well, basically I'm just hoping to find the place and the way I can add `%H:%M:%S` or the place where I can substitute it for `%I:%M\ %p`.

Comment: @notrace fair enough. I've removed my comments as it is more clear that your question is on topic as it is about a standalone (albeit web-active) application rather than just an actual webapp.

Comment: Assuming it's a webapp you probably can't as its not running locally so you would have to check the options to see whenever there are some in that regards. Looking at the [debian wiki entry](https://wiki.debian.org/skype) and what you wrote I'd assume you're not using the package but the webapp (web.skype.com) and a such should be using your own browser. If you do you might be able to use a third party addon or script to do the conversion for you.

Comment: @Seth Both of them use a webapp-style GUI (e.g., no GTK, no QT), including the "standalone" one.